# Unzipped files in S3 have different name

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, flyway

I am using flyway to handle db procedure and query migrations for PostgreSql.
When I build my project on local, a zip flyway file is generated and I can easily migrate those to my local postgres.
But when same zip file is uploaded to S3 and I try to migrate flyway on aws rds, flyway info shows only some stored procedures. Other procedures name gets changed like below :

original name : V0.0.6__get_some_function_name.sql

changes to : V0.0.6__get_??some_function_name.sql

And flyway info shows only version V0.0.1 to V0.0.5 pending and does not show from V0.0.6.

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the name contains some unicode unprintable characters that are most likely getting incorrectly decoded on the S3 or RDS side. It is yet unclear where exactly the problem is but since you mention that you are able to migrate to local PostgreSQL then it seems like the problem is not on the export side but on the import side.

It might be the collation configuration on your RDS instance, or something else in-between.